# Bad: Kali Linux Copy And Paste Problems

Tags: linux, windows, copy-paste, kali-linux

### Kali Linux Copy And Paste Problem:

So I've been having this problem so much its became a huge pain, it gets aggravating having to type out such long sentences from my host computer without being able to copy and paste from it, I've tried everything I could find online and I mean everything and none of the solutions seemed to work, I even tried downloading **Kali Linux** on a **Virtual Machine** instead of a **Virtual Box** (Which was a nightmare to setup for me) and it along with a bunch of other features didn't work either (Probably because I'm not good with setting it up), but I didn't care because I mainly wanted it to work on my **Virtual Box**, I noticed something today though after I reinstalled **Kali Linux** for my Virtual Box (I figured reinstalling it would do the trick) and it kind of did, at least until i did "***sudo apt-get upgrade***" then the copy and paste feature stopped working, I've spent awhile dealing with this but I'm fed up, please do your best and leave some ideas, anything, I really just want this to work. Thanks.

### Other Infromation:

• I'm running the latest version of **Oracle V Virtual Box 64-Bit**: 6.1.4 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.4/VirtualBox-6.1.4-136177-Win.exe

• I've downloaded **Kali Linux Virtual Box 64-Bit**: Version 2020.1 https://images.offensive-security.com/virtual-images/kali-linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64.ova

• I'm running **Windows 10 Latest Version*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy & paste is broken in the Guest Additions 6.1.4 r136177. Either downgrade the Guest Additions or install 
the 6.1.5 [test build](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) of the Guest Additions.

See the related post on U&L: [Copy paste not working on Virtual box 6.1 running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 Machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569993/copy-paste-not-working-on-virtual-box-6-1-running-ubuntu-18-04-on-windows-10-mac)

Comment: So this?: https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-6.1.5-136449-Win.exe

Comment: Download [VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.5-136459.iso](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.5-136459.iso), mount it in your virtual cd-rom and run `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` as root. Reinstalling everything probably works too, but I haven't tested that. I'm still running 6.1.4 r136177 with the newer Guest Additions.

Comment: Seems a bit hard to understand but I think I know what you mean, but was the link you gave me for Linux or the virtual box cuz i noticed it was an Iso file

Comment: Put the ISO in the virtual drive of your Kali VM, it's `Devices -> Optical Drives -> Choose a disk file...` in the menu, change to the directory of the mounted ISO in Kali and run the Linux installer as root.

Comment: See: [Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions in Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-kali/)

Comment: Actually its working by just Using the basic install, just downloading **Kali Linux** and choosing to open it with **Oracle VM VirtualBox** (The Version I sent you), everything seems to work and i ran "**sudo apt-get upgrade**" no problem and everything still works including copy and paste :D, though I will save your comment in case this problem occurs once again, (It most likely will lol) thank you so much though!!!